# named pipe could not be activated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, wcf-binding, named-pipes

I am working with an WCF application that interacts with a sql server database and consumed by an asp.net mvc application. It runs in IIS 7.5.

Up to recently the protocol used for interaction with the services from the mvc app was via http. However I have recently changed to named pipes.

I have run in to the problem though where the pipe is dying from lack of use or for example when a change is made in the web.config of the wcf app. When the mvc app tries to interact the following error occurs:

'The requested service, 'net.pipe://localhost/MyService.svc' could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information.'

The only way round it is to browse to the http endpoint in a web browser to activate the service/pipe.

I checked in the app pool and it is set up to start automatically.

Any ideas why this is occuring and how it could be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a section under: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752253.aspx which talks about enabling named pipes under WAS which should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help - yes I followed these steps but still same issue.